# How to properly run a Symfony task in the background from an action?

Tags: php, symfony1, exec, fork

What is the correct way to run Symfony tasks in a separate process. My first guess would be to use fork/exec, but according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#99350), you can't do it with anything that keeps open file descriptors or connections (like MySQL). So that doesn't sound like its an option. Another alternative is to do `exec('symfony taskname &')`, but that seems like a hack. Is that the best I can do? Is there a third way?

Comment: The pcntl_fork function only works for the cgi version of php. If you're running php via apache it's a no go. Using exec is pretty much the only way of doing it with apache but it's definitely ugly and must run silently to execute at the same time.

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out that you have to redirect stdout to a file to get it to actually run. Is that what you mean by "run silently"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
exec('nohup ' . sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/symfony TASKNAME >/dev/null &');
```

You have to redirect STDOUT, or else it won't run in the background (though you don't have to use /dev/null if you want the actual output). In my case I set up all my tasks to use Symfony's file logger, so it wasn't an issue.

I'm still looking for a better solution though. This seems like a hack.

Answer (score 4):

The way this is generally handled is to use a task queue. When you want to do a background process, add it to a queue of some kind (you could use your database, or you could use an actual queue daemon like beanstalkd). You then have some daemonized procces(es) whose job is to pull work out of the queue and perform it.

Answer (score -7):

Php knows no multithreading.
And yes it is a big flaw in php IMO.
There is a way to do multithreading, but it is not recommended. It's complex, and it is ugly and it is asking, no calling out for problems.

So, i think the best you can do is something like exec, or maby somthing like calling a webservice like call?